# Give access to only a dataset in bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-iam

I have a GCP project and want to give an employee access to only a single dataset inside of BigQuery and that's all. I tried giving this employee access by going to the dataset-sharing section and assigning the role `BigQuery Data Owner` but then the employee cannot see the project at all to be able to access BigQuery. should I be adding additional roles to his account?

Comment: You have a button "add" on the upper right corner of the explorer panel. You can add external source like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did figure it out.

First I had to give the employee the `BigQuery Job User` permission on the project level (this was important to give the employee permission to query the tables that he can view) with the `bigquery.datasets.get` permission (you can add this to a custom role).

Then it's totally up to you. For me I did give him the `BigQuery Data Viewer` permission on a table level for the tables that I want to give him access to.

This can also be applied at the dataset level.

How to grant the permissions:

[at dataset level](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#granting_access_to_a_dataset)
[at table or view level](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-access-controls#create)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this step-by-step approach:

1. Ensure the employee has at least the `BigQuery Resource Viewer` role at the project level. This allows the employee to see the project itself.
2. Go to the dataset you want to grant access to.
3. Add the employee's Google account email to the dataset's permissions.
4. Assign the necessary roles for the dataset. For read-only access, you can use `BigQuery Data Viewer`. You can assign `BigQuery User` or `BigQuery Job User` roles if they need more privileges.

After making these adjustments, the employee should be able to see the project and access the specified dataset in BigQuery while maintaining proper permissions

Comment: Following your approach resulted in the following:
Now the user can view all the datasets & tables in BigQuery. I tried assigning the BigQuery Resource Viewer role instead and it worked as intended.

Answer (score -1):

You need to navigate to the [IAM & Admin](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=my-project) page and grant access to the employee here. If they are not listed, click on grant access and give them the `Viewer` role. This should give them enough access to view the project.

Next, head back over to [BigQuery](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=my-project) and click on the share button next to your dataset. Then click the Add Principal button and grand the user at least `BigQuery Data Viewer` or `BigQuery Data Editor` role.

After this, they should have access to only the one dataset in your BigQuery Project.